# How can I get application its own pid. How to get cpu usage by application in Java without external libraries?

Tags: java, cpu

For example in linux htop: http://scr.hu/1det/r1ghl and when I check in my application cpu usage by pid: 27914 it should print me 51%. How to this do?

```
   public static int calcCPU(long cpuStartTime, long elapsedStartTime, int cpuCount) {
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long totalAvailCPUTime = cpuCount * (end - elapsedStartTime);
    long totalUsedCPUTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - cpuStartTime;
    //log("Total CPU Time:" + totalUsedCPUTime + " ns.");
    //log("Total Avail CPU Time:" + totalAvailCPUTime + " ns.");
    float per = ((float) totalUsedCPUTime * 100) / (float) totalAvailCPUTime;
    log(per);
    return (int) per;
}

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // 2 is the smallest prime
    if (n <= 2) {
        return n == 2;
    }
    // even numbers other than 2 are not prime
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // check odd divisors from 3
    // to the square root of n
    for (int i = 3, end = (int) Math.sqrt(n); i <= end; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    int mb = 1024 * 1024;

    int gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    /* PHYSICAL MEMORY USAGE */
    System.out.println("\n**** Sizes in Mega Bytes ****\n");
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    //RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    //operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean os = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        // log(start);
        //number of available processors;
        int cpuCount = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
        Random random = new Random(start);
        int seed = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
        log("\n \n CPU USAGE DETAILS \n\n");
        log("Starting Test with " + cpuCount + " CPUs and random number:" + seed);
        int primes = 10000;
        //
        long startCPUTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        start = System.nanoTime();
        while (primes != 0) {
            if (isPrime(seed)) {
                primes--;
            }
            seed++;

        }
        float cpuPercent = calcCPU(startCPUTime, start, cpuCount);
        log("CPU USAGE : " + cpuPercent + " % ");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

I tried this but I think I can't check with this method usage cpu by one application

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do this at the moment out of the Java toolbox without calling native methods and/or third party libraries and/or calling platform specific command line commands.

The Java [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) object is very limited at the moment.

The good news is that a new [Process facility is coming in Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102):

> Summary
>
> Improve the API for controlling and managing operating-system
>   processes.
>
> Motivation
>
> The limitations of the current API often force developers to resort to
>   native code.
>
> Description
>
> Java SE provides limited support for native operating-system
>   processes. It provides a basic API to setup the environment and start
>   a process. The process streams can, since Java SE 7, be redirected to
>   files, pipes, or can be inherited. Once started, the API can be used
>   to destroy the process and/or wait for the process to terminate.
>
> Many enterprise applications and containers involve several Java
>   virtual machines and processes and have long-standing needs which
>   include:
>
> The ability to get the pid (or equivalent) of the current Java virtual
>   machine and the pid of processes created with the existing API.
>
> The ability to enumerate processes on the system. Information on each
>   process may include its pid, name, state, and perhaps resource usage.
>
> The ability to deal with process trees, in particular some means to
>   destroy a process tree.
>
> The ability to deal with hundreds of sub-processes, perhaps
>   multiplexing the output or error streams to avoid creating a thread
>   per sub-process.

---

Edit: suggestion to use in case you want to user third party library.

You might want to take a look at [Sigar](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home):

> Overview The Sigar API provides a portable interface for gathering
>   system information such as:
>
> System memory, swap, cpu, load average, uptime, logins Per-process
>   memory, cpu, credential info, state, arguments, environment, open
>   files File system detection and metrics Network interface detection,
>   configuration info and metrics TCP and UDP connection tables Network
>   route table This information is available in most operating systems,
>   but each OS has their own way(s) providing it. SIGAR provides
>   developers with one API to access this information regardless of the
>   underlying platform. The core API is implemented in pure C with
>   bindings currently implemented for Java, Perl, Ruby, Python, Erlang,
>   PHP and C#.

Comment: can you deliver such a library that will allow me to check this ?